# Check existence of limit with definition

Tags: calculus, limits

want to check the existence of the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x} $ using the definition.

For that do we use the epsilon delta definition?

If yes, I have done the following:

Let $\epsilon>0$. We want to show that there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. if $0<|x-0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$.

We have that $\left |f(x)-1\right |=\left |\frac{x}{x}-1\right |=\left |\frac{x-1}{x}\right |=\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}$.

How can we continue?

Comment: You have a small typo, it should be $\frac{x}{x}-1 = \frac{x-x}{x} = 0$ (or more directly, just note $x/x=1$)

Answer (score 2):

$\frac x  x-1$ is not $\frac  {x-1 }x$. It is $\frac {x-x} x$ which is $0$.

Comment: So is the limit equal to 0? Isn't it 1?

Comment: The limit  is $1$. In fact $\frac x x=1$ for all $x \neq 0$ which implies $|\frac  x x-1|=0<\epsilon$ for all $x \neq 0$. So you can take any $\delta >0$ in the definition of limit. @MaryStar